# Stop Scrolling auto in EditText

Tags: java, android, scrollbar

I use `EditText` with option `scrollbars=vertical` to write my data in my app.
The problem is when I received data my scrollbar automatically goes down.
I would like to prevent automatic scrolling when I press the screen

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edCapteur"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9CE49C"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"

    />
```

I use this for add data in my edidtext:

```
edidtext.append("data");
```

Comment: Add this in your manifest file - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" And 

android:isScrollContainer="false"

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: welcome:) @Killian

Answer (score 1):

This is because the cursor of `edittext` is moved to the end. You need to keep the cursor at its original position

```
int originalPosition = edidtext.getSelectionStart();
edidtext.append("data");
edidtext.setSelection(originalPosition);
```

Comment: no it will not work because android:focusable="false"